# Redirect user based on role when they try access a particular page

Tags: users, redirect, user-roles

Please how can I redirect a user base on the role when they try to access a particular page?

I would need the code to do this, please.

Answer (score 0):

```
function redirect_non_vendors() {

    global $wp;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    $role_needed = 'vendor';
    $page_to_check = 'secret/page/url';
    $redirect_url = home_url( '/go-here/' );

    if ( ! in_array( $role_needed, (array) $user->roles ) && $page_to_check === $wp->request ) {
        wp_redirect( $redirect_url );
        exit;
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_non_vendors' );
```

You'll want to replace three things here:

`vendor`: the role that someone has to have to access the page

`secret/page/url`: the "particular page" you mention in your question

`/go-here/`: the URL to send a user to if they are not the role

Comment: Thank you but please how can I redirect already login users who don't have a specific role to another page when they try access a specific content they don't have access it , I just don't want to use a plugin

Comment: That sounds complex, the sort of thing that membership plugins are built around. But I understand that you don't want to use a plugin. Some questions for you: Are you trying to do this on one page or many pages? Do users get sent to the same page all the time? Why are users created that don't have any role at all? (Didn't know that was possible!)

Comment: What I am trying to do is this , if Mr. A with subscriber role try to access a page meant only for vendor it should redirect them back to a page i choose

Comment: Sorry about that, I wasn't really answering your question. I updated my answer to do a better job of it.